# qmake not found although Qt installed

Tags: qt, unix, qmake

I created Qt project in MS Visual Studio 2010, I am trying to port it to linux OS.
I got **Linux**, on which **Qt 4.6.3** is **installed** (came with distribution package).

I need to generate the **Makefile** for my project (project_name.pro),
so I try `qmake -project` and get `command not found`

As I got Qt installed (executing qtconfig in terminal allows me to know qt version) it quite unevidient & strange for me why having Qt I can't use it's utility qmake?

Could you please offer me some solution of this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What distro is that? Probably qmake is in separate package, e.g. in Debian it's qt4-qmake package, also look for some qt-devel, qt4-devel or similar.

```
pwadas@vao:~$ which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
pwadas@vao:~$ ls -al /usr/bin/qmake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 mar 26  2012 /usr/bin/qmake -> /etc/alternatives/qmake
pwadas@vao:~$ update-alternatives --list qmake
/usr/bin/qmake-qt3
/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
pwadas@vao:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
qt4-qmake: /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
pwadas@vao:~$
```

Comment: Astra Linux. But behaves very much a like Ubuntu ). I am complete neebee in OS.
"which qmake" - returned nothing therefore i came to the conclusion that qmake utulity not installed.
I need to install it. 
is executing aptitude install qmake will be enough?
What steps should I undertake to install qmake properly?

Comment: Never heard about Astra Linux, where did you get it? :) however with debian/ubuntu clone, "apt-cache search qt4 |grep qmake" and then aptitude install PACKAGENAME or  apt-get install PACKAGENAME should do..

Comment: cool! Thank you very much! I have installed it, so I shall spend interesting time porting my project. To mention although it is debian clone it isn`t provided free of charge, my release costed 1300$ to my firm which ordered it, for that price you get some security tools, which I haven`t used yet, as I installed and configured it a day ago. Interesting that distro goes without installed make, gcc, g++ utulities. Ok, so thanks again for usefull information! Have a nice day)

Answer (score 6):

Seeing as the Qt3/Qt4 libraries overlap in all the Linux distros I've tried, I thought it might be a good idea to provide a more thorough answer to resolving this issue.  If you're running a debian-based distro, the previously-suggested answer to use `dpkg` might work; however, on other Linux distributions, such as Fedora, for example, that won't quite work.

A more suitable solution, regardless of what distribution you're running, if you have `alternatives` installed is to do this:

> `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/qmake qmake /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 10`

Then, for good measure, you can follow that with: `update-alternatives --set qmake /usr/bin/qmake-qt4`

Comment: There's also a [link here](http://jpnurmi.kapsi.fi/blog/2008/03/16/how-to-switch-qt-version-in-ubuntu/) describing the alternatives configuration of "hand-made" compilations of the qt library in Ubuntu; as well as the use of the "slave" option.